# More efficient use of aws s3 sync?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Lately, we've noticed that our AWS bill has been higher than usual.  It's due to adding an `aws s3 sync` task to our regular build process.  The build process generates something around 3,000 files.  After the build, we run `aws s3 sync` to upload them *en masse* into a bucket.  The problem is that this is monetarily expensive. Each upload is costing us a ~$2 (we think) and this adds up to a monthly bill that raises the eyebrow.

All but maybe 1 or 2 of those files actually change from build to build.  The rest are always the same.  Yet `aws s3 sync` sees that they all changed and uploads the whole lot.

The documentation says that `aws s3 sync` compares the file's last modified date and byte size to determine if it should upload.  The build server creates all those files brand-new every time, so the last modified date is always changed.

What I'd like to do is get it to compute a checksum or a hash on each file and then use that hash to compare the files.  [Amazon s3 already has the etag field which is can be an MD5 hash of the file.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html)  But the `aws s3 sync` command doesn't use etag.

Is there a way to use etag? Is there some other way to do this?

The end result is that I'd only like to upload the 1 or 2 files that are actually different (and save tremendous cost)

Comment: S3 charges for storage, API requests, and potentially for data transfer out depending on destination, but it doesn't charge for data transfer in. Do you know for sure what's causing the increase in costs?

Comment: The "aws s3 sync" command only replaces files that are different, so I don't see how this could be the cause. It is definitely something else causing the high cost, and at 2$ per build there is something seriously wrong with the setup that needs investigating. As the other person who answered mentioned, go through CloudTrail to pin point the events, or take a closer look at what your build is actually doing.

Answer (score 5):

The `aws s3 sync` command has a `--size-only` parameter.

From [aws s3 sync options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html#options):

> `--size-only` (boolean) Makes the size of each key the only criteria used to decide whether to sync from source to destination.

This will likely avoid copying all files if they are updated with the same content.

Comment: But with `--size-only`, `aws s3 sync` can fail to upload a file that has been changed, but is still the same size.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to s3 sync or cp you could use s5cmd

https://github.com/peak/s5cmd

This is able to sync files on the size and date if different, and also has speeds of up to 4.6gb/s

Example of the sync command:

```
AWS_REGION=eu-west-1 /usr/local/bin/s5cmd -stats cp -u -s --parents s3://bucket/folder/* /home/ubuntu
```

Comment: Size and date are the metrics that the AWS CLI already respects

Answer (score 1):

S3 charges $0.005 per 1,000 PUT requests ([doc](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)), so it's *extremely* unlikely that uploading 3,000 files is costing you $2 per build. Maybe $2 per *day* if you're running 50-100 builds a day, but that's still not much.

If you really are paying that much per build, you should enable CloudTrail events and see what is actually writing that much (for that matter, maybe you've created some sort of recursive CloudTrail event log).

> The end result is that I'd only like to upload the 1 or 2 files that are actually different

Are these files the artifacts produced by your build? If yes, why not just add a build step that copies them explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

*[rclone](https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_sync/)* can do this:

> Doesn't transfer files that are identical on source and destination,
> testing by size and modification time **or MD5SUM**

Use the --checksum flag which uses size+checksum instead of size+modtime to test for changes:

```
rclone sync source:path dest:path --checksum
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue that I got was using wildcard * in the --include option. Using one wildcard was fine but when I added the second * such as */log.*, it looked like sync tried to download everything to compare, which took a lot of CPU and network bandwidth.